# Load TXT into postgres database, with non-present columns filled in as null

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm a bit of a python novice, so forgive me if there is a simple solution that I am failing to see. I have a large number of txt files (~280) that I need to read into a table in a postgres database. The table is structured such that it contains all possible columns/variables that are present in the txt files. Consider the example below...

`file1.txt`:

```
ID | Var_A | Var_B
1  | Apple | Dog
2  | Peach | Bird
```

`file2.txt`:

```
ID | Var_A | Var_C
5  | Grape | Cat      
3  | Apple | Dog
```

`file3.txt`:

```
ID | Var_B | Var_C
7  | Apple | Cat
6  | Peach | Bird
```

Ideally, I would like my table to encompass all of the data in the txt files, with columns/variables that are not present in the txt file, to be recorded as a blank or null. (For the sake of demonstration and clarity, I've written them as null below.)

postgres_table:

```
ID | Var_A | Var_B | Var_C
1  | Apple | Dog   | NULL
2  | Peach | Bird  | NULL
3  | Apple | NULL  | Dog
5  | Grape | NULL  | Cat
6  | NULL  | Peach | Bird
7  | NULL  | Apple | Cat
```

Given the large number of files, this process will need to be automated. I have been using psycopg2 in python for this task, and have made many prior attempts, none of them successful. I believe that a `COPY` query will be most efficient, (there are millions of lines of data,) but I am having difficulty with the non-present columns in txt files when trying to copy it in.

```
cursor = db.cursor()
query = "COPY postgres_table FROM '{}'(DELIMITER('|'));".format(~/file1.txt)
cursor.execute(query)
db.commit()
```

This query produced the following error:

```
psycopg2.DataError: missing data for column "Var_C"
```

Perhaps someone can see what I don't. I would also be interested in other potential solutions to this task.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to read the text file as a string, then modify the string to effectively add the nulls, then pass this to the format method instead of the file.

So you could read the first line of a file, see which fields were missing (compare it to the fields in the database table) and add "|" in each line of the string at the point where there was a missing field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use temporary table to load data from all files to it and then do what you want with it using `plpgsql` or even `plpython`.

For example:

```
-- Destination table
create table if not exists dest(
  id int,
  var_a varchar,
  var_b varchar,
  var_c varchar);

begin; -- Start transaction

-- Temporary table to load data from all files
create temporary table tt(
  tt_order serial,
  tt_id varchar,
  tt_var_1 varchar,
  tt_var_2 varchar,
  tt_file varchar)
on commit drop; -- It will be drooped at the end of transaction

-- Load data, header will be included
copy tt(tt_id, tt_var_1, tt_var_2) from '~/file1.txt' (delimiter '|', header false);
update tt set tt_file = '~/file1.txt' where tt_file is null;

copy tt(tt_id, tt_var_1, tt_var_2) from '~/file2.txt' (delimiter '|', header false);
update tt set tt_file = '~/file2.txt' where tt_file is null;

copy tt(tt_id, tt_var_1, tt_var_2) from '~/file3.txt' (delimiter '|', header false);
update tt set tt_file = '~/file3.txt' where tt_file is null;

-- Remove spaces
update tt set
  tt_id = trim(tt_id),
  tt_var_1 = trim(tt_var_1),
  tt_var_2 = trim(tt_var_2);

select * from tt;

-- Result is
/*
 tt_order | tt_id | tt_var_1 | tt_var_2 |   tt_file   
----------+-------+----------+----------+-------------
        1 | ID    | Var_A    | Var_B    | ~/file1.txt
        2 | 1     | Apple    | Dog      | ~/file1.txt
        3 | 2     | Peach    | Bird     | ~/file1.txt
        4 | ID    | Var_A    | Var_C    | ~/file2.txt
        5 | 5     | Grape    | Cat      | ~/file2.txt
        6 | 3     | Apple    | Dog      | ~/file2.txt
        7 | ID    | Var_B    | Var_C    | ~/file3.txt
        8 | 7     | Apple    | Cat      | ~/file3.txt
        9 | 6     | Peach    | Bird     | ~/file3.txt
(9 rows)
*/

-- Move data to destination table
do language plpgsql $$
declare
  r record;
  q text;
begin
  for r in select * from tt order by tt_order loop
    if lower(r.tt_id) = 'id' then -- If header from next file
      -- Build insert query
      q := 'insert into dest (id, ' || lower(r.tt_var_1) || ', ' || lower(r.tt_var_2) || ') values ($1::int, $2, $3)';
    else
      -- Insert data record
      execute q using r.tt_id, r.tt_var_1, r.tt_var_2;
    end if;
  end loop;
end; $$;

commit;

select * from dest;

-- Result is
/*
 id | var_a | var_b | var_c 
----+-------+-------+-------
  1 | Apple | Dog   | 
  2 | Peach | Bird  | 
  5 | Grape |       | Cat
  3 | Apple |       | Dog
  7 |       | Apple | Cat
  6 |       | Peach | Bird
(6 rows)
*/
```